# How to get values that are present in each date?

Tags: sql

I have a time series database of account numbers and their balances. Not all account numbers are present in each date.

For example:

| date | account_id | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | 10.0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2 | 100.0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 3 | 78.0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 1 | 40.0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 2 | 200.0 |
| 2021-01-03 | 1 | 0.0 |
| 2021-01-04 | 1 | 0.0 |
| 2021-01-05 | 1 | 0.0 |
| 2021-01-06 | 1 | 7.0 |
| 2021-01-06 | 2 | 4.0 |
| 2021-01-06 | 3 | 0.0 |

Just the `account_id 1` appears in all dates.

I want a SQL query that returns that account.

| date | account_id | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | 10.0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 1 | 40.0 |
| 2021-01-03 | 1 | 0.0 |
| 2021-01-04 | 1 | 0.0 |
| 2021-01-05 | 1 | 0.0 |
| 2021-01-06 | 1 | 7.0 |

This is just an example. It can be many accounts instead of just one.

I generated this query with Python, which of course not optimal when the number dates grow:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_name 
WHERE account_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT account_id FROM table_name WHERE date_prod = '2021-01-01'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT DISTINCT account_id FROM table_name WHERE date_prod = '2021-01-02' 
    INTERSECT
    SELECT DISTINCT account_id FROM table_name WHERE date_prod = '2021-01-03'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT DISTINCT account_id FROM table_name WHERE date_prod = '2021-01-04'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT DISTINCT account_id FROM table_name WHERE date_prod = '2021-01-05'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT DISTINCT account_id FROM table_name WHERE date_prod = '2021-01-06'
)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please, see the edit

Comment: I see an SQL question only, no Python involved yet. What is your DBMS - please add a tag like [tag:postgres] etc. ?  What is still a bit unclear: Which "question" should the SQL query really answer?

Answer (score 2):

You want to compare the unique dates against each account ID with the unique dates across the whole table. Something like this should work.

```
SELECT table1.date1,
       table1.account_id,
       table1.balance
FROM table1
  INNER JOIN (SELECT account_id,
                     COUNT(DISTINCT date1) AS distinct_dates
              FROM table1
              GROUP BY account_id) account_dates ON table1.account_id = account_dates.account_id,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT date1) AS expected_dates FROM table1) entire_table
WHERE account_dates.distinct_dates = entire_table.expected_dates;
```

Comment: it is erroring out in mysql. with this message. `Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() AS expected_dates FROM table1 GROUP BY account_id' at line 6`

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aQmr3uC6eDXvNVV2EvGXWe/0 check this out

Comment: Exactly, the query doesn't work but I understand the intuition behind it!

Comment: OK, thanks @magnus. I've corrected the query to a) add the ON join condition and b) calculate the expected dates without using a window function

Answer (score 0):

Suppose column `date_prod` is of type DATE.

Given `MAX(date_prod) - MIN(date_prod) AS period_in_days .. WHERE account_id = x` is a number of days.
and the number of rows per account is `COUNT(date_prod) .. WHERE account_id = x`.

When both numbers are equal for each account `x` then you can select values or balances that are **present in each date** ( daily records ).

It depends on your DBMS which SQL function or query syntax can solve that.